# Opening a pygame file in main from another file (mygame)

Tags: python, function, module, pygame

So i'm trying to open my game file by import mygame, butit does not seem to work'here is the code( i will explain more after the code)

```
import mygame
'''THI IS THE MAIN FILE'''
print("hello")
while True:

    ui = input(">>")
    if 'hello' in ui:
        print("hi!")
    if 'how are you' in ui:
        print("im fine")
    if 'game' in ui:
        mygame() 
        '''open the game'''
```

this is the mygame file(just randomly copied a small pygame code, cause i only want to understand if this can actually be done)

```
import pygame as p,random
q=p.display
T=16
b=q.set_mode([256]*2).fill
l=[]
d=a=x=1
c=p.event.get
def mygame():
    while not(x&528or x in l):
     l=l[a!=x:]+[x]
     while a&528or a in l:a=random.randrange(512)
     b(0);[b(99,(o%T*T,o/32*T,T,T))for o in l+[a]];q.flip();p.time.wait(99);D=d
     for e in c(2):
      v=e.key-272;n=((v&2)-1)*[1,32][v<3]
      if-n-D and 0<v<5:d=n
     c();x+=d
```

CONCLUSION: i only want to start the game if a trigger('game') is in the input of the main but in this case when i run the main the game opens first without the trigger.
this is the other type of pygame which includes pygame.init() (also much easier to understand than the last one)

```
import sys, random, time, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def gameg():
     pygame.init()
     font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
     screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
     pygame.display.set_caption("Bomb Catching Game")
     pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
     game_over = True
     lives = 3
     score = 0
     game_over = True
     mouse_x = mouse_y = 0
     lead_x = 0
     pos_x = 300
     pos_y = 460
     bomb_x = random.randint(0, 500)
     bomb_y = -50
     vel_y = 0.3
     white = 255, 255, 255
     red = 220, 50, 50
     yellow = 230, 230, 50
     black = 0, 0, 0
     def print_text(font, x, y, text, color=(255, 255, 255)):
          screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
          imgText = font.render(text, True, color)
          screen.blit(imgText, (x, y))
     while True:
          for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
               elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                    mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos
                    move_x, move_y = event.rel
               elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if game_over:
                         game_over = False
                         lives = 3
                         score = 0


          keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
          if keys[K_ESCAPE]:
               sys.exit()
          if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
               lead_x -= 1
          if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
               lead_x += 1


          screen.fill((0, 0, 100))

          if game_over:
               print_text(font1, 100, 200, "<CLICK TO PLAY>")
          else:
               #move the bomb
               bomb_y += vel_y

               #has the player missed the bomb?
               if bomb_y > 500:
                    bomb_x = random.randint(0, 500)
                    bomb_y = -50
                    lives -= 1
                    if lives == 0:
                         game_over = True
               #see if player has caught the bomb
               elif bomb_y > pos_y:
                    if bomb_x > pos_x and bomb_x < pos_x + 120:
                         score += 10
                         bomb_x = random.randint(0, 500)
                         bomb_y = -50

               #draw the bomb
               pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (bomb_x-4, int(bomb_y)-4), 30, 0)
               pygame.draw.circle(screen, yellow, (bomb_x, int(bomb_y)), 30, 0)

               #set basket position
               pos_x = lead_x
               if pos_x < 0:
                    pos_x = 0
               elif pos_x > 500:
                    pos_x = 500
               #draw the basket
               pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, (pos_x-4, pos_y-4, 120, 40), 0)
               pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (pos_x, pos_y, 120, 40), 0)

          #print # of lives
          print_text(font1, 0, 0, "LIVES: " + str(lives))

          #print scores
          print_text(font1, 500, 0, "SCORE: " + str(score))

          pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a few issues with both python codes.

In your `mygame.py` , you are calling `q.set_mode([256]*2).fill` , which opens up a new window. And this is at module level , hence it runs directly when you call the module or run the python file.

In your other file (from which you want to run the game) , the below code -

```
if 'game' in ui:
    mygame() 
    '''open the game'''
```

Actually tries to call the module `mygame` directly, and not the function 'mygame()`inside the module`mygame`, for that you need to do -`mygame.mygame()` .

---

A few simple changes to your code, to make it work would be -

mygame.py

```
import pygame as p,random
def mygame():
    q=p.display
    T=16
    b=q.set_mode([256]*2).fill
    l=[]
    d=a=x=1
    c=p.event.get
    while not(x&528 or x in l):
        l=l[a!=x:]+[x]
        while a&528 or a in l:
            a=random.randrange(512)
        b(0)
        [b(99,(o%T*T,o/32*T,T,T)) for o in l+[a]]
        q.flip()
        p.time.wait(99)
        D=d
        for e in c(2):
            v=e.key-272
            n=((v&2)-1)*[1,32][v<3]
            if-n-D and 0<v<5:
                d=n
        c()
        x+=d
    q.quit() #Quit the display at the end of the game.
```

A few changes I made to the code -

1. Added all the lines outside the function to inside the `mygame()` function.
2. Added code to close the display - `q.quit()` - after the game ends.
3. Refactored the code to a make it look a bit better.

The main python code -

```
import mygame
'''THI IS THE MAIN FILE'''
print("hello")
while True:

    ui = input(">>")
    if 'hello' in ui:
        print("hi!")
    elif 'how are you' in ui:
        print("im fine")
    elif 'game' in ui:
        '''open the game'''
        mygame.mygame()
    elif 'exit' in ui:
        break
```

Few changes here -

1. Calling the function as - `mygame.mygame()` - instead of `mygame()` .
2. Added a `elif` block , to exit out of the game gracefully. Otherwise the only way to exit out of the block would have been `Ctrl+C` .

---

**EDIT**

In the latest Code example added by OP , the issue is in the `print_text()` method , where the screen keeps getting reset due to the line - `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))` .

We do not need to Just removing that line should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Anand S Kumar i understand it all, but how do you actually apply this concept to the other code i just posted by editing my original question? i     actually used def **(): on all functions but when i call the function the game is in black screen? why is it like that and how to fix it? thanks again!

Comment: Can you also add the code you are using to call this?

Comment: the code is actually the exact same as the main from your answer

Comment: @ManopPhysics Edited the answer to include that